# Is it fine to call setState in setState callback?

Tags: reactjs

I need to update one state based on the actual value of another state. Feels like setting state in callback on another one is a bad idea.

Do you know whether there is better solution for that?

```
const [day, setDay] = useState(null);
const [month, setMonth] = useState(day);

const onNextClick = useCallback(() => {
  setDay((day) => {
    const newDate = addDays(day, 1);
    if (newDate.getMonth() !== day.getMonth()) {
      setMonth((month) => addMonths(month, 1));
    }
    return newDate;
  });
}, []); // keep the function reference
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good practice. according to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
You don’t have to use many state variables. State variables can hold objects and arrays just fine, so you can still group related data together. However, unlike this.setState in a class, updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.
in your case you could have something like this:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(null);

const onNextClick = useCallback(() => {

setDate((date) => {
const newDate = addDays(date.day, 1);
if (newDate.getMonth() !== date.day.getMonth()) {
  const newMonth = addMonths(date.month, 1));
}
return {day: newDate, month:newMonth};
});
}, []); // keep the function reference
```

treating the date as an object with day and month fields.
hop this helps.

Comment: Where exactly does it say that it's not safe? I couldn't find it.

Comment: I meant to say its not a good practice. it produces something that addresses your scenario and thats is using object or array as state object. what you did is not a good practice. consider having 3 more state variables to update.